# Get index of Shuffle Range on 2D Array php

Tags: php, arrays, random, range, shuffle

I want to random 80*13 digits for genetic algorithm where 80 is popsize and 13 is dna size. And I trying to get index of range value on 2d array. To make a random int from 1 - 13 without duplicate where i mean 2d for 80 rows and 13 column. like this

```
$arr = [0][0]; //this is output will be same with the table value in row1 col1
$arr = [0][1]; //this is output will be same with the table value in row1 col2
...
$arr = [0][12]; //this is output will be same with the table value in row2 col1
$arr = [1][1]; //this is output will be same with the table value in row2 col2
..
```

i have a code like this.

```
<?php
function randomGen($min, $max) {
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    return array_slice($numbers, 0);
}
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Kromosom ke-</th>
        <th colspan="13">Stasiun Kerja</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php
        for ($i=1; $i <= 13; $i++) { 
        ?>
            <th>
                <?php echo $i;?>
            </th>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<?php
    for($i = 0; $i < 80; $i++) {
        $no = 1;
        echo "<td> v".$no."</td>";
        $arr[$i] = randomGen(1,13);
        for ($j=0; $j <= 12; $j++) {
            $arr[$j] = randomGen(1,13);
            echo "<td>";
            echo $arr[$i][$j];
            echo "</td>";
        }
            echo "</td><tr>";
            $no++;

    }
    // print_r($arr[0][0].' '); // for see the value is same or not
    ?>
```

when i try to printout $arr[0][0], thats value is not same with the table in row1 col1.

Any ideas?

> UPDATE!

great solution for this problem is answer from Rainmx93 , thats work for me. Thankyou very very much

Comment: Why you call randomGen() in second for loop?

Comment: i think thats for index colum of array, like $arr[0][$j] its mean $arr[0][$j] where $j =0 -> 12, maybe?

Comment: No, you already have multidimensional array in first loop, just remove that second function `randomGen()` call and everything should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first for loop you already generating multidimensional array, but now in second loop you override all array elements on each iteration, you need to remove that second function call.
Your code should look like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 80; $i++) {
    $no = 1;
    echo "<td> v".$no."</td>";
    $arr[$i] = randomGen(1,13);
    for ($j=0; $j <= 12; $j++) {
        echo "<td>";
        echo $arr[$i][$j];
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</td><tr>";
    $no++;

}
```

Comment: yeah! this is work for me, thank you very very much, sir.